は contrasting vs を
I saw a sentence like this:
"理由は聞かなくったって分かる…私が弱すぎるから."
I know that this is the contrasting は, but I am not sure when to use this version over the を　version:
"理由を聞かなくったって分かる…私が弱すぎるから"
My questions are:
1 - Is my interpretation below correct:
理由を聞かなくったって分かる…私が弱すぎるから。 (neutral): "I don’t need to ask the reason, I know."
理由は聞かなくったって分かる…私が弱すぎるから。 (with contrast): "As for the reason, I don’t need to ask, I already know (though I might need to ask about other things)."
2 - When would you use を over は　in my case?

This question is similar to: "は + verb" instead of "を + verb"?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It is a common substitution to use は over を when in a negative sentence. For example:

雨ですので、明日テニスをしません。

Is the same as

雨ですので、明日テニスはしません。

I would have assumed some question on this site already addressed this, but I guess I am wrong.
I think your interpretation is correct, as the writer already understands he is too weak, so he understands without the reason being heard.
んなああ。

There are lots of previous questions that might address this, or at least be similar enough, but it's not easy to search for such a thing. I tried to offer a candidate, though.

It was mentioned in my textbook back in 8th grade, so sorry I assumed it was more widespread.

No, it's a good instinct to have. But a Stack Exchange site for languages will naturally have a harder time tracking and using duplicates than a site for a more technical topic such as programming.

In my case, it would add contrast, sure, but in what scenario would you use the を version of my sentence for example? You said it's the same with negative sentences, but in my case, it's not negative, is it? Does を make it a netural statement without contrast?

聞かなく is negative.

Oh, I missed that. My bad and thanks for correcting me. You said it's the same in negative sentences, but is there really no difference? no emphasizing, nothing?

There probably is a VERY niche nuance, but in normal conversation, they are basically the same.
